# Questionable "Low Quality Post" Review Audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was in the "Low Quality" review queue today and came across an answer that wasn't great, but in my view was complete. It was three short paragraphs of text and included a link to an off-site guide. I said it "Looks OK" because as I understand it the purpose of this queue is not to judge the quality of the answer per se but the value of the post in general. What I mean by that is that earlier on in my SO life, I flagged some really bad answers for deletion and was told that for bad answers that are complete and formatted well but simply not very good answers to a specific question, one is supposed to downvote not close/delete.

So, I question whether this particular example is a good test in the queue since it seems (in my opinion) to be a satisfactory post even if it isn't a great answer to the particular question.

And, telling me that this post is spam/offensive is confusing because it appears to be neither.

Here's the edit history, which I was instructed to look at:

[image]

And the image telling me this was was spam/offensive, which I disagree with.

[image]

Comment: Even if that isn't *spam* per se, surely it's blatantly off-topic?

Comment: @user0000000 Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655562/is-there-a-server-application-that-converts-aiff-to-mp3

Comment: @JonK The review was for the answer, not the question. Therefore it can't be off-topic.

Comment: That depends on how you define "on-topic". In the context of the *question*, yes, it's on-topic. But as far as I know the VLQ review *doesn't show you the question*, so you *can't* use it as the context for the answer. In which case it becomes "*is this answer on-topic in the context of StackOverflow?*", and the answer to that is a resounding **no**.

Comment: @JonK Answers are not on-topic or off-topic; only questions. And the review queue does show you the question, it's just not highlighted.

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree on whether or not an answer can be off-topic then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that was an audit was because it was flagged as spam and removed as such. That post was clearly spam for faasoft.com and their products. Take a look at what was behind the link at the end of that answer. It was pure advertising for a commercial product.

While you didn't have this context, I just found six other users that spammed that same link in the last several weeks, and this user spammed that link three times before they were stopped. This is a spam ring that has attacked the site for years.

When reviewing answers, be extremely critical of answers by 1-rep users that end with a link to some site. Spammers are starting to paste reasonable-looking text (usually plagiarized from here or elsewhere) in answers, and then place links at the very end or in the body text. In the review queues, you need to be on the lookout for this, because we absolutely cannot have people approving spam and allowing it to live on the site.

If something seems odd or promotional in nature, but you're not confident enough to flag it as spam, use an "other" flag and point out what you saw. We'll gladly dig into things and see if this really was spam or just a well-meaning user who happened to phrase their answer in a suspicious manner.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is really 'not-an-answer'. The OP from 3 and half years ago is asking for a server application to take in aiff and convert to mp3 presumably to forward on to a flash client somehow. The answer doesn't provide a solution for that and neither does the currently existing answer either. It's more of a 'please recommend a tool' question and the question should probably be closed. The answer should have been deleted because it's '**Not an Answer**' and that would have been the correct reason for deleting. It might be thinly veiled spam, but at the face of it does not seem like it is. We can't correct the past, but if you take the time to read the post and not rush through approval, then you probably would have came to the same decision that I came to regarding the entirety of the post including the question and answer.

Now, you may feel like you are rushed because there is no **lock** on approvals yet whereas while you are approving, someone cannot trump you while you are taking the time to approve. That's the one thing about the queue that I loathe.