# Another Questionable Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I posted about this issue [the other day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261623/questionable-low-quality-post-review-audit), but I'm getting skeptical about some of the review audits. I recently saw this answer in the Low Quality Post queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5173081

The answer includes a complete code example, is from an 8k+ rep user, and includes a link to an open source tool on GitHub. Apparently it is spam. How is this spam?

[Here's a link to the actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780188/reliable-way-to-detect-browser-version-and-plattfom-in-php/24083827#24083827). The accepted answer on the question has no code and includes nothing more than a link to sourceforge.

Based on [Brad Larson's answer to my previous question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261683/2338862), what makes it spam might be (1) that it was posted multiple times (something we could not possibly know if we come across this post in the review queue), or (2) that it includes a link to commercial product. But this includes a link to an open-source tool. So, what's the issue?

**Here's the verbatim text of the answer just as an FYI:**

Look at the [Wolfcast BrowserDetection PHP class](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection).

[BrowserDetection](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection) is more reliable than [Browser](https://github.com/cbschuld/Browser.php). I tested 14,250 user agents and I got 99.95% positive results with BrowserDetection and 85.56% with Browser.

The code to do it would be something like:

```
require_once('BrowserDetection.php');

$browser = new BrowserDetection();

$platform = $browser->getPlatform();
//You would test a platform like this:
$isIPhone = $platform == BrowserDetection::PLATFORM_IPHONE;
$isMobile = $browser->isMobile();

$browserName = $browser->getBrowser();
//You would test a browser like this:
$isIE = $browserName == BrowserDetection::BROWSER_IE;

$browserVersion = $browser->getVersion();
//You can also test versions like this:
$isVerElevenOrMore = $browser->compareVersions($browserVersion, '11.0') !== 1;
//compareVersions returns 1 if $sourceVer < $compareVer,
//0 if $sourceVer == $compareVer or
//-1 if $sourceVer > $compareVer
```

Comment: @devnull Exactly.

Comment: Whatever logic was used to delete the answer mentioned should also apply to the  [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13780332/2235132).

Comment: Mods have tunnel vision, it seems.  They are unable to see other answers in the same post and use their logic consistently.  Alas!

Comment: Another possibility is that [50K+ rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts) entitles you to post something that would otherwise be regarded as spam.

Comment: For those who can't see the deleted post in question, here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4728d98e-a97d-4448-9371-88c3bcb47840/view-source).  (Hope that this link, per se, doesn't _qualify_ as spam!)

Comment: I think the problem might be that review audits are not drawn from more-or-less recent questions/posts, and therefore include answers from questions that were fine back then, but are offtopic right now.

Comment: @devnull If you can't see deleted answers, you can't see deleted answers. Not even if you link the revisions.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I've added the answer text above.

Comment: I've just realized someone has already stated the same complaint about this identical answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261032/is-it-possible-to-review-a-review-audit